# How do I solve the Sturm-Liouville problem with boundaries that include 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the Sturm-Liouville problem

$x^2 y''+ 2xy'+ \lambda y =0$

for the following boundary conditions:

(a) $y(0)=0\  \mbox{and}\  y(1) = 0$

(b) $y(\epsilon)=0\  \mbox{and}\  y(1) = 0$

with $0<\epsilon<<1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you tried anything or have any thoughts on the problem? Regards

Comment: Well, I managed to solve it for the x$\in$[1,2] case by trying $y=x^\alpha$ with complex $\alpha$; it worked out smoothly! But the only thing that comes to my mind for boundary conditions (b) is an identical solution. But I can't make sense of the limiting case where $\epsilon$ goes to infinity. For the BC (a) I am not sure at all! I suspect the eigenfunctions will be different but I have no idea how so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Unsolvable, since the only solution that satisfies those condition is the trivial solution $y(x)=0$ .

(b)

Let $x=e^t$ , than the ODE becomes $y''(t)+y'(t)+\lambda y(t)=0$ with conditions $y(\ln\epsilon)=0$ and $y(0)=0$

$\therefore\lambda=\dfrac{n^2\pi^2}{(\ln\epsilon)^2}+\dfrac{1}{4}$ , $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ , and the corresponding solution is $y(x)=\dfrac{C}{\sqrt{x}}\sin\dfrac{n\pi\ln x}{\ln\epsilon}$

Comment: Thanks! Now what do you think the limit is when $\epsilon$ goes to zero?

Comment: @Farid Farjad: $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}\dfrac{C}{\sqrt{x}}\sin\dfrac{n\pi\ln x}{\ln\epsilon}=0$ , but we will not consider $0$ as the non-trivial solution, so this can also implies that (a) is unsolvable.